# Why does getrefcount increase by 2 when put inside a function?

Tags: python, cpython, reference-counting

Consider the following code.

```
import sys

a = [1, 2, 3]

def foo(x):
    print(sys.getrefcount(x))

foo(a) # prints out 4 -- but why?
```

When we invoke `foo(a)` and when `print(sys.getrefcount(x))` executes, the array `[1, 2, 3]` is referenced by `a`, by the parameter `x` of the function `foo` and by the parameter of `sys.getrefcount`. I expected 3 to be printed out. What have I missed?

Comment: Added the CPython tag since this question is about a CPython implementation detail

Comment: As a hunch: the "by the parameter `x`" reference is actually two: one reference for the args tuple to `PyObject_Call`, and another reference for the local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: I am far from an expert in CPython internals. This answer is the best of my understanding of what's going on from having skimmed the CPython source code. It may not be the whole story, or applicable to all cases.</sub>

---

The reference you're missing is the *local variable* `x`, which is different from the argument reference.

Internally, the call to `foo` is carried out by invoking [`PyObject_Call`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#c.PyObject_Call) with a tuple of the function arguments. The [strong reference](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-strong-reference) held by that tuple is the one reference that gets added in the case of calling `sys.getrefcount(x)`. However, calling `foo` is different because the arguments aren't acted on directly in the C code but instead need to be made available as local variables that are accessible during the subsequent bytecode execution. The structure that stores the Python-accessible local variables keeps its own strong reference to the argument objects. Hence why the reference count gets incremented a second time when calling a Python function.